# sed substitute replaces curly braces ${i} - How to stop that?

Tags: sed

I am trying to replace `13` with `21` using sed:

```
echo "for i in {1..5}; do commands for FILE13 > output_${i}; done" | sed 's/13/21/g'
```

And my output looks like this:

```
for i in {1..5}; do commands for FILE21 > output_2; done
```

`13` was replaced with `21` but additionally `${i}` was replaced with `2`.

Why this happens? And how to stop sed replacing mu curly braces content?

**Edit**

What if my command looks like this:

```
echo 'for i in {1..5}; awk'{( do commands)}' FILE13  > output_${i}; done' | sed 's/13/21/g'
```

And I can't replace double quotes to single quotes as I am getting `bash: syntax error near unexpected token`('`

Is the only solution to use `\` to escape braces?

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. Why are you editing a shell command? Do you just need an outer for loop that iterates over FILE13 and FILE21? If this is for use at an interactive shell, read up on your shell's history mechanisms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't sed replacing the curly braces, it's the shell. Change the double quotes for the echoed string to single quotes.

Compare:

```
$ echo "for i in {1..5}; do commands for FILE13 > output_${i}; done"
for i in {1..5}; do commands for FILE13 > output_; done

$ echo 'for i in {1..5}; do commands for FILE13 > output_${i}; done'
for i in {1..5}; do commands for FILE13 > output_${i}; done
```

If the string you are echoing contains single quotes itself, then use double quotes and escape the `$` or handle the quote directly:

```
$ echo "for i in {1..5}; awk'{( do commands)}' FILE13  > output_\${i}; done"
for i in {1..5}; awk'{( do commands)}' FILE13  > output_${i}; done

$ echo 'for i in {1..5}; awk'"'"'{( do commands)}'"'"' FILE13  > output_${i}; done'
for i in {1..5}; awk'{( do commands)}' FILE13  > output_${i}; done
```

Answer (score 1):

Is the argument of echo a literal string? Then:

```
echo "for i in {1..5}; do commands for FILE13 > output_\${i}; done" | sed 's/13/21/g'
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot embed single quotes in a single quoted string.  Try:

```
echo 'for i in {1..5}; awk'"'"'{( do commands)}'"'"' FILE13  > output_${i}; done'
```